# Properly stop QVideoWidget when opening dialog

Tags: c++, qt, video

I'm trying to show a dialog over a window that contains a video view. This is the code that opens the dialog:

```
MyDialog* dialog=new MyDialog(this, /*...*/);
ui->centralTabWidget->setEnabled(false);
QVideoWidget* vid=findChild<QVideoWidget*>("player");

if(vid!=0){
    //Here is what I've tried so far to keep the view from freezing
    qDebug()<<"stopping mediaplayer";
    QMediaPlayer* player=vid->findChild<QMediaPlayer*>("mediaplayer");
    player->stop();
    player->setVideoOutput((QVideoWidget*)0);
    vid->setVisible(false);

    qDebug()<<"stopped mediaplayer";
}

dialog->exec();
```

And this is the code that creates the videoview:

```
    if(/*condition*/){
       QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget(this);
       vw->setObjectName("player");
       vw->installEventFilter(this);

       QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(vw);

       ui->videoScrollArea->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);

       vLayout->addWidget(vw);

       player->setVideoOutput(vw);

       player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("./Videos/" + target->returnVid().at(0)));

       player->setMuted(true);

       player->play();
    }
```

The output contains both "stopping mediaplayer" and "stopped mediaplayer". When the dialog is shown, the program (including the dialog) stops reacting to clicks, but Windows doesn't classify it as "not responding". If the videoview isn't created, this freeze does not happen. Moving the application window to background doesn't cause this, either.

I've tried setting the dialog's geometry to not overlap with the videoview, but this hasn't helped.

I've been using kits "Qt 5.4.2 MinGW 32bit" and "Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit" on Windows 7 on two different computers.

Comment: `the program stops reacting to clicks` but the dialog still react, doesn't it?

Comment: No, the dialog doesn't react to clicks either.